# Change Old Wordpress Post Date Year

Tags: posts, wp-query, date

I have old WordPress posts that were published way back in 2017, 2018, and 2019. I would like to republish this content. Basically, what I want is that all content from 2017 to be republished in 2021, 2018 in 2022, and 2019 in 2023. Is there any possible way I can do this without doing some changes to the database? Is it possible to have a function that I can put in my functions.php to achieve this goal?

Comment: I simple solution would be querying posts from those years and update the `post_status` to `future` and `post_date` to desired value using `wp_insert_post`.

Comment: Hi @Abhik Thanks for that but since I'm new to this. Do you have any idea on how to code that? Thanks.